# PHP SoapClient iterating lists when there is only one element

Tags: php, soap-client

I'm using the webservice `https://ptefatturapa.aruba.it/fatturapaupload/uploadws?wsdl` and I'm calling the method `ListFatturaPa`

Inspecting the result with var_dump, I noticed the field `fatturapalist` is an object when there is only one element, and an array of objects when there are two or more elements.

Using `foreach` to iterate elements give me troubles when there is only one element. There is an elegant solution to iterate that element avoid writing an `if` condition testing the number of elements?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem... did you manage to solve it?

Comment: I ended up distinguishing the two cases with an if statement. I didn't find a more stilish way to achieve the same result